# Spark Exception: Python in worker has different version 3.4 than that in driver 3.5

Tags: python, apache-spark, version, cluster-computing

I am using Amazon EC2, and I have my master and development servers as one. And I have another instance for a single worker.

I am new to this, but I have managed to make spark work in a standalone mode. Now I am trying cluster. the master and worker are active (I can see the webUI for them and they are functioning).

I have Spark 2.0, and I have installed the latest Anaconda 4.1.1 which comes with Python 3.5.2. In both worker and master, if I go to pyspark and do os.version_info, I will get the 3.5.2, I also have set all the environment variables correctly (as seen in other posts on stackoverflow and google) (e.g., PYSPARK_PYTHON).

There is no 3.4 version of python anywhere anyways. So I am wondering how I can fix this.

I get the error by running this command:

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([1,2,3])
rdd.count()
```

error happens for the count() method:

```
16/08/13 18:44:31 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 1.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 17)
org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 123, in main
    ("%d.%d" % sys.version_info[:2], version))
Exception: Python in worker has different version 3.4 than that in driver 3.5, PySpark cannot run with different minor versions

at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:193)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:234)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:152)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:63)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:85)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
16/08/13 18:44:31 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 1.1 in stage 2.0 (TID 18)
org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 123, in main
    ("%d.%d" % sys.version_info[:2], version))
Exception: Python in worker has different version 3.4 than that in driver 3.5, PySpark cannot run with different minor versions
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:193)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:234)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:152)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:63)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:85)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 9):

Since you already use Anaconda you can simply create an environment with the desired Python version:

```
conda create --name foo python=3.4
source activate foo

python --version
## Python 3.4.5 :: Continuum Analytics, Inc
```

and use it as `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON`:

```
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=/path/to/anaconda/envs/foo/bin/python
```

Comment: Didn't work. I did this on both the driver and master, and I can see the (foo) at the beginning of each line in my ssh window, so it is doing what it's supposed to. But the error still stays the same.

Comment: It worked by doing something different now. I used your suggestion to create a foo environment with python 3.5 on both master and worker. which didn't solve the problem. But instead, now, I created a 3.4 environment only on master (since it seems it think slave is 3.4), and it all worked nicely. So if there is no way to make the worker to be recognized as the 3.5 that it is, I will make this question as resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue. There are several possible reasons:

- One of your workers had python3.4 but you didn't notice it. Please go to each worker to check `PYSPARK_PYTHON`. That is, if you set `PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3`, go to each worker to type `python3` and check the version.
- You connect to the wrong workers. Check your `SparkContext` config and make sure what your workers are.

I have spent more than ten hours to find the same issue with you. But the root cause for me is the wrong connection.... TAT

Answer (score -3):

Just install the required python version and update it in your environment